# Trying to build a dynamic list inside a BottomSheet in flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart, dynamic

So i'm building a user list inside a BottomSheet. There is an Widget that is fixed on the list start, and when i click it opens another screen, used to create another user. When i confirm, it should update that user list, but it doesn't.

this is how it works, except for the problem with the list:

[image: This is how it works]

This is the code for UserBottomSheet:

```
    return Container(
          height: 100,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.deepOrange,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topRight: Radius.circular(20),
              topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
            ),
          ),
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2, left: 2, right: 2),
            height: 100,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.orange,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
              ),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
              child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: widget._userRoundCardList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final userContent = widget._userRoundCardList[index];
                  return UserRoundCard(userContent, RoundCardSize.LARGE);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      void addUser(User user) {
        debugPrint("USER LIST -> ${user.userName}");
        widget._userList.add(user);
        widget._userRoundCardList.add(InitialsRoundCard(user));
      }

This is the "add user" button widget, used to navigate to "New User" Screen:

    return InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context)
                .push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewUser()))
                .then((user) => UserBottomSheetState().addUser(user));
          },
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.add,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

This is the widget used as button to navigate to the New User screen:

```
return InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    Navigator.of(context)
        .push(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewUser()))
        .then((user) => UserBottomSheetState().addUser(user));
  },
  child: Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
    child: Icon(
      Icons.add,
    ),
  ),
);
```

And this is the Screen where I create a new user:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Add New User"),
  ),
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16.0),
          child: TextField(
            controller: _nameController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: "USERNAME",
              hintText: "Type your name",
            ),
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: double.maxFinite,
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              final _userName = _nameController.text;

              if(_userName.trim() != ""){
                User newUser = User(_userName);
                debugPrint("NEW USER: ${newUser.toString()}");
                Navigator.pop(context, newUser);
              }else{
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("FILL ALL.")));
              }
            },
            child: Text("CONFIRM"),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Each of these codes are in separate files. The problem is that when I click the confirm button after typing the user name, the userList dont get updated and the user isn't inserted into the list.

Anyone has any idea of how can I fix this?

**Update #1**

I'm listening to the changes made in the list using .then from Navigator, that calls `addUser( )` on the UserBottomSheet Widget.
This funciton should update the list using:

```
setState(( ) => widget._userRoundCardList.add(InitialsRoundCard(user)));
```

I don't know if the problem has something to do with the call on addUser( ), it is like this:

```
.then((user) => UserBottomSheetState().addUser(user));
```

and it is set in the button widget, that is in a separte file.
The concept of Context is a bit confusing for me yet

Comment: Welcome to  StackOverflow. How are you listening to the changes made to your List ?

Comment: I've updated the post with the information, thanks for the help.